# "Account Not In This Store" Error

Tags: mac-appstore

I'm trying to subscribe to an app (downloaded from the MacOS App Store) and I keep getting the error

```
Account Not In This Store
Your account is not valid for use in the U.S. store.
You must switch to the Brazilian store before purchasing.
```

But I AM logged into the Brazilian store. I've seen a few mentions of this error, tried to follow the suggestions (logging in and out, restarting the computer, change store region and change back) to no avail. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you download from the Brazil store or is it from a link. Anyway as a first attempt delete the app and reinstall.

Comment: @Mark downloaded from the store, but subscription link was within the app. Tried reinstalling. But found out the solution, will post here

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution:

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app and changing stores didn't work, but I followed the ""Account Not In This Store" error message with "Change Store” button" tip from https://mindnode.com/support/kb/payment-issues and managed to subscribe!